# Waiting at a road junction

Tags: probability

This is a basic probability question which might already have been asked. If so, my apologies.

At a road junction, at any given moment in time, the probability that a car passes by within thirty minutes is $p$. What is the probability that a car passes by within five minutes?

If $X$ is the random variable denoting the waiting time for the first car to appear then what kind of distribution function does it have? Would it be exponential? And what is the answer to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we are given that *at any given moment in time* the probability of a car passing within 30 minutes is $p$, we may infer that the distribution is [*memoryless*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness). Since the distribution also seems to be continuous, we may infer that the distribution is indeed Exponential (as this is the only memoryless continuous distribution).

Thus we have that the distribution is exponential with cdf such that $F(30)=p$. That is (using the formula for Exponential cdf), we want to find $\lambda$ such that $1-e^{-\lambda \cdot 30}=p$. Ultimately we want to use this to find $F(5)$, the probability that a car passes in five minutes. Can you take it from here?